# Sum rows values in column on MySQL

Tags: mysql

This is my sql query on database MySQL:

```
mysql> SELECT
    sArea,
    `2014`,
    `2015`,
    `2016`,
    `2017`
FROM
    `doTableAreas`
WHERE
    LEFT (sArea, 2) IN ('XM');
```

And this is the output:

```
+-------+------+------+------+------+
| sArea | 2014 | 2015 | 2016 | 2017 |
+-------+------+------+------+------+
| XM2A  |    0 |    1 |    4 |    5 |
| XM2B  |    0 |  231 |  527 |   51 |
| XM4A  |    0 |   87 |  287 |   46 |
| XM4B  |    0 |   77 |  112 |    7 |
| XM4C  |    0 |    0 |   42 |    1 |
| XM6A  |    0 |   57 |  108 |   18 |
| XM7A  |    0 |  280 |  456 |   52 |
| XM7B  |    0 |  568 |  579 |   47 |
+-------+------+------+------+------+
8 rows in set
```

How to do for have this other output, instead, with total of single year?

```
+-------+------+------+------+------+
| sArea | 2014 | 2015 | 2016 | 2017 |
+-------+------+------+------+------+
| XM2A  |    0 |    1 |    4 |    5 |
| XM2B  |    0 |  231 |  527 |   51 |
| XM4A  |    0 |   87 |  287 |   46 |
| XM4B  |    0 |   77 |  112 |    7 |
| XM4C  |    0 |    0 |   42 |    1 |
| XM6A  |    0 |   57 |  108 |   18 |
| XM7A  |    0 |  280 |  456 |   52 |
| XM7B  |    0 |  568 |  579 |   47 |
| Total |    0 |  1301|  2115|   227|
+-------+------+------+------+------+
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look up the syntax with rollup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `Union`should work:

```
SELECT
    sArea,
    `2014`,
    `2015`,
    `2016`,
    `2017`
FROM
    `doTableAreas`
WHERE
    LEFT (sArea, 2) IN ('XM')
Union
SELECT
    "Total",
    sum(`2014`),
    sum(`2015`),
    sum(`2016`),
    sum(`2017`)
FROM
    `doTableAreas`
WHERE
    LEFT (sArea, 2) IN ('XM');
```

Answer (score 1):

GROUP BY modifier [with ROLLUP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html) was built for this.

```
mysql> SELECT
    sArea,
    sum(`2014`) as `2014`,
    sum(`2015`) as `2015`,
    sum(`2016`) as `2016`,
    sum(`2017`) as `2017`
FROM
    `doTableAreas`
WHERE
    LEFT (sArea, 2) IN ('XM');
GROUP BY SArea, `2014`, `2015`, `2016`, `2017` with rollup
```

though sarea will be NULL instead of saying "total"

Comment: in this case you can use `SELECT IFNULL(sArea,"Total")` .... to get "Total" as sArea label

Comment: True; in this case.  if we had multiple subtotals then we'd have a more complicated case statement.